# How to access azure web site using ip address

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-custom-domain

I have created one azure web app service (S1:1), I have registered custom domain  (TXT, CNAME & A records in DNS) for this site. I am able to access site using FQDN (https://xyz.pqr.com) but when I am using IP address to access this site it give me below error.

[image]

**Why am I doing this?**
I want to redirect another application to this application using DNS resolver for that it make use of IP address.

Answer (score 0):

***The **`404`** error occurs due to multiple reasons, please check the below to resolve the error:***

- Please check your domain resolves to the apps **`IP`** address by using [**whatsmydns.net**](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)
- Please check whether the A record is pointing to the wrong **`IP`** address.
- Check whether the custom domain is having correct **`A record`** and **`CNAME`** configured.
- The old IP address may be cached, so trying to clear the cache.

Make sure the **custom domain** is present in the Azure App Service like below:

[image]

> Please **note** that, using both a **`CNAME`** record and an **`A record`** for the same domain can cause a conflict and prevent the domain from being resolved.

Please check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-domain-ssl-certificates#dns-cant-be-resolved) for few causes and solutions that may give you a pointer to solve the issue.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Azure WebApps Custom Domain 404 error by AjayKumar-MSFT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09e4f893-c020-450b-86cc-7d3af11ae2af/azure-webapps-custom-domain-404-error-flush-dns?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

[Azure web app custom domain problem by Ryan Hill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565321/azure-web-app-custom-domain-problem.html)

Comment: Hi @RukminiMr-MT , were you able to access app service with ip address ever?